# Adding Image to a list elements Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating the list elements dynamically using the below code:

```
var entry = document.createElement('li');

entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Geralds Patta Inc.'+
'1249 Downing Street, Dallas, Tx, 75202, USA'));  
list.appendChild(entry);
```

I have to add one icon at the end of this list as shown in the image:

[image]

How can I add those icons dynamically at the end of list?

Comment: Are using font awesome icons ?

Answer (score 1):

After a long and hectic search found a method. Hope this helps. Please [go through this article on CSS custom variables](https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/) or [MDN Docs on CSS Custom variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

Note : IE doesn't support this method according to the MDN Docs.

**USING HTML and CSS:**

```css
#list > li:after
{
    content:"";
    background-image:var(--iconimg);
    background-size:cover;
    width:var(--iconwidth);
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul style="--iconwidth:20px;" id="list">
    <li style="--iconimg:url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416');">Test</li>
    <li style="--iconimg:url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416');">Test</li>
    <li style="--iconimg:url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416');">Test</li>
    <li style="--iconimg:url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416');">Test</li>
    <li style="--iconimg:url('https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416');">Test</li>
</ul>
```

In case you are using, [Font Awesome Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/)

```js
var faicons = ["calculator","calendar","calendar-check-o","calendar-minus-o","calendar-o","calendar-plus-o","calendar-times-o","camera","camera-retro","car","caret-square-o-down","caret-square-o-left"];

var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#fa > li");
elems.forEach(function(elem,index){
    elem.classList.add("fa");
    elem.classList.add("fa-"+faicons[index]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="fa">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

[BootStrap Glyphicons](https://glyphicons.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/#)

```js
var bootstrapicons = ["asterisk","plus","eur","euro","minus","cloud","envelope","pencil","glass","music"]
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#bs > li");
elems.forEach(function(elem,index){
    elem.classList.add("glyphicon");
    elem.classList.add("glyphicon-"+bootstrapicons[index]);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="bs">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using fontaweoms..Need basic solution.

Comment: Is the icon specified by a class or an image ?

Comment: it's an image png file

Comment: @min2bro Updated the answer. Hoper it helps.

Comment: @min2bro Does it fulfil your requirements ?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is add :after in CSS for li  element
for example:

```
li:after{content:""; background:yourimage; width:15px; height:15px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
```

if you want jquery

you can call method like this

```
   function addIcon(entry, iconClass, iconHtml) {
       $('<i>', {
           'class': iconClass,
           'html': iconHtml
       }).appendTo(entry);
   }
```

if you have just image, use below method
     function addIcon(entry, imgClass, src) {
           $('', {
               'class': iconClass,
               'src': iconHtml
           }).appendTo(entry);
       }

```js
var imgIcons = ["calculator.png","camera.png","camera-retro.png","car.png","caret-square-o-down.png"];

$("#fa li").each(function(index){

 
       $('<img>', {
           'class': 'img_class',
           'src': imgIcons[index]
       }).appendTo($(this));
 

});

function addDynamicallyTextIcon(text, icon, parent){

var container=$('<li>',{
    'html' : text
  }).appendTo(parent);
  ($('<img>', {
           'class': 'img_class',
           'src': icon
       })).appendTo(container)

}
addDynamicallyTextIcon( 'Geralds Patta Inc.'+
'1249 Downing Street, Dallas, Tx, 75202, USA','.../images/logo-jquery.png','#addimg_whenAddContent');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="fa">
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
</ul>


<ul id="addimg_whenAddContent">
<li>Test1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No Can't do it using css, since for each li the icons will be different so need to create that dynamically.

Comment: and you can't use jquery? you need just javascript code?

Comment: I can use Jquery as well

Comment: you can use some thing like this but your calss or html should be variable that you can pass to function:                                                                             $('<i>',{
  'class' : 'fa fa-icon',
  'html': 'html text'
}).appendTo(entry);

Answer (score 0):

Should you try this after adding fontawesome library to your project

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">`

```
entry.appendChild(
   document.createTextNode(
      'Geralds Patta Inc.'+
      '1249 Downing Street, Dallas, Tx, 75202, USA' +
      '<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>'
));
```

Comment: @min2bro I edited solution and add image to end of your list please check it, I'll hope it was useful for you;)